# How to stop this small roof from leaking?

Tags: leak, roof

We have water stains in the ceiling drywall underneath this small section of roof.

I suspect it's due to the loose metal that's on top of the shingles.  The fasteners on the top of the metal are all sealed still, but the metal literally lifts up by hand.

In the image, a gap on the left side is clearly visible.  I suspect the water is entering through the nail holes, but I'm not 100% sure.

[image: leaky roof pic]

**How do I properly fix this?  Is there a certain "maintenance" required with this metal piece?**

Comment: Because water runs downhill, the leak could be anywhere above the source, and could be to either side. The window could be the culprit. The metal is above the shingles for the same reason the shingles under the window are over the next row down. Short of pulling off the siding and taking out the window and making sure everything is properly flashed and counterflashed, it's more likely a design issue than a maintenance one.

Comment: More pictures of the overall area esp above and sides of window all the way to the higher roof peak would be helpful to identify potential trouble spots.

Comment: @benrudgers nailed it.  It was the window.

Comment: That's why they pay me the big bucks...or should. Glad you got it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are getting leaks through that gap. Wind driven ran can push water right under that flashing.

You can install sealant underneath the flashing like Aravindakshan K suggested. I would take it a step further, and add roofing nails with the neoprene washers on them to hold the flashing closer to the roof.

I have the same problem with my front porch. It doesn't have proper footings and has sunk over time causing a separation in the flashing. Your roof appears to have the same situation. It is likely that that separation will continue unless you address the structural issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can seal the joint with polyurethane sealant. This will make the joint water tight and it is expandable up to 900%, as it can accommodate most of the movement.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the window had some cracked caulking that was missed multiple times by the roofers and myself.  The section continued to leak after the flashing was secured, and roofing nails sealed.

After re-caulking the window, no sign of water for multiple years.

Comment: That's worrying. Caulk should never be the last line of defense. Sounds like that window is flashed improperly, or not at all.